# Android = select column1 from table where column2 = column3 order by id desc

Tags: java, android

**how to solve this problem**

**i'm trying to get the last meter from the table which is similar car number using by id desc**

**As in the picture**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9uhn.png)

**here is my code**

```
 String CarN = carNumber.getText().toString();
                SQLiteDatabase dataBas = logDB.getReadableDatabase();
                int active = 0;
                String activeCar =String.valueOf(active);

                Cursor cursor = dataBas.rawQuery("select "+CarLoadingToSaveUtils.NEW_METER_READING +" from "+
                        CarLoadingToSaveUtils.TABLE_CAR_LOADING_SAVE +" where "+CarLoadingToSaveUtils.CAR_NUMBER_LATTER+" = "+ CarN + " order by "+
                        LogDB.KEY_ID +" desc ",new String[]{activeUser});

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    int index6 = cursor.getColumnIndex(CarLoadingToSaveUtils.CAR_NUMBER_LATTER);
                    String Num = cursor.getString(index6);

                        oldMeteReading.setText(Num);
                } else {
                    oldMeteReading.setText("0");
                }
```

**When i run the code i get this error**

**android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "1234": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9uhn.png)): , while compiling: select newMeteReading from carLoadingSave where carNumber =? 1234 H order by id desc**

Answer (score 0):

CarN value (? 1234 H) need to be between quotes

Replace this :
CarLoadingToSaveUtils.TABLE_CAR_LOADING_SAVE +" where "+CarLoadingToSaveUtils.CAR_NUMBER_LATTER+" = "+ CarN + " order by "+

by :
CarLoadingToSaveUtils.TABLE_CAR_LOADING_SAVE +" where "+CarLoadingToSaveUtils.CAR_NUMBER_LATTER+" = '"+ CarN + "' order by "+

Comment: i get this error  ( java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters. )